# Linking source code from SVN project to another project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have built a project (Project A) in Eclipse with my own classes, and I have a different project which is just a checked out folder from SVN (Project B). I want to link Project A to subfolders in Project B. I went to link source from the configure build path in Project A and was able to get all the subfolders from Project B of interest into linked folders in Project A. When I opened these new linked folders, I got an error message on the package address/name (I guess that was the original SVN package  address/name, so I deleted the package statement and the errors went away. So now I have no package statement at the top of my linked folders. But when I try to reference classes in the linked folders from the classes I wrote in Project A, it cannot find/import any of the classes from the linked folders.

Could anyone explain to me why Eclipse is unable to connect to my linked classes from SVN?

Thanks,
Christie

Comment: I'm not really sure why the package names from the imported project would cause a problem. Still, there might be a workaround. You cou try exporting project B as a jar and use that in your build path for project A. I'm assuming you did import all of project B, not just part of it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use a jar because I want to be able to edit the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svnrdump to do this.
This link might be useful
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html

Suppose you have two directories of the project a and project b, then for each of your project repositories:

```
svnadmin dump > projectname.dmp
```

then all you have to do is make directory and load for each of the dump files:

```
svn mkdir "<repo url>/projectname"
svnadmin load --parent-dir "projectname" <path to repository>
```